# Android Studio : Error converting bytecode to dex:Multiple dex files define Ljavax/mail/internet/ParameterList$ToStringBuffer;

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.0.1, and while running the program I get this error:

[image: this]

**My build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mrunal.myadmin"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
}
 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**manifest files**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.felicity.myadmin">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Email_Activity"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I already tried

- clean & rebuild
- removed the second compilation of jar

I have search lot of related questions on **SO** but nothing helps me.
please, anyone, help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved,

I just change `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

To

`implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'`
 and it works

Answer (score 0):

Updating your multidex is just temporary remedy for your problem. The same problem gonna bite you again if you're using proguard for your release apk.

The problem probably because you're using the same library with:

```
implementation 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.3'
```

and

```
implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
```

Use only one.

You also don't need using:

```
implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
```

if you're using:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

You probably don't need using a multidex for your apk because your dependencies is not exceed 65k limitation.